# Android emulator on AMD Phenom X4 965 BE or some replacement

Tags: android, android-emulator, amd-processor

i've got a box with CPU like in title. I would like to run Android emulator on it but when I do, I've got this error and screen is black in emulator:

> Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this
> machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will
> address this in a future release.
>
> Emulator: emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following
> feature(s) required for x86 emulation: SSSE3
>
> Emulator: Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly!

I know that google updated their emulator. Hypervision and hyper-v is enabled.
And i have installed proper versions of both AS and emulator.

If i can't run emulator with this CPU are there any alternatives for google emulator? Genymotion has free version for personal use (earning money is not allowed). Microsoft android emulator is outdated.

Edit:
I just discovered that I can run KitKat emulator (google) but Lollipop doesn't start.

Comment: Which version of PC OS are you running (Windows 7, 8, 10 or Linux/32 or 64 bit)?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 pro